# What explains the contrast in suicide mortality versus attempts between men and women?

Tags: abnormal-psychology

It's said that men in general die from suicide about 3 times more than women, but women make about 3 times more attempts than men. So, men have around 9 times more mortality per attempt.

Some sources for this claim are the following:

[Differences in Suicide Among Men and Women](https://www.verywellmind.com/gender-differences-in-suicide-methods-1067508)

[Gender differences in suicide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_differences_in_suicide)

What are the main reasons that could explain this difference?

Comment: Doesn't the Wikipedia article you linked already provide an answer, including references to other sources?

Comment: @BryanKrause, sort of, it explains that women make more use of drug overdose, or in general less lethal methods, but I don't think that explains on its own 9 times less "efficiency" in dying due to suicide.

Comment: Why not? Seems pretty straightforward to me. What in the references linked there is not convincing to you?

Comment: I personally think that a "properly planned" substance overdose is more likely to cause a death than the difference shows, on top of that, an important percentage of suicidal women use hanging, which is an effective method for suicide so that makes me find the huge difference even more strange. I could be wrong about the first thing, it's just what it looks like to me.

Comment: It's better to rely on data when it is available rather than intuition. I don't see any other way to convince you if the data don't.

Comment: @BryanKrause, in any case, Wikipedia itself mentions that the different suicide methods only explain the difference partially, so it's worth it to put the question here to see if someone can give a more complete explanation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105380/discussion-between-user2638180-and-bryan-krause).